# Passing context to a function [Javascript graphics]

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an HTML document that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link   rel = "stylesheet"
                type = "text/css"
                href = "landscape.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id = "heading">My Landscape</h1>
        <canvas id = "landscape" width = "800" height = "600">
            landscape
        </canvas>
        <script type = "text/javascript"
                src = "landscape.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's landscape.js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('landscape');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
context.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
var mySky = new sky(40, 40);
mySky.render(context);

function sky(x, y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    function render(theContext){

        theContext.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
        theContext.fillRect(x, y, 150, 100);

    }

}
```

Now, the first part - the "context.fillStyle = " and the "context.fillRect()" - work fine. It shows up as a red rectangle in my browser (using Firefox on a Mac btw).

But when I try to create a sky object and then pass the context to render it, nothing happens. I can't figure out why it won't execute the render function on the sky object.

Am I misunderstanding how JS objects work?

Here is the (very simple) CSS, in case someone wants to try running it all.

```
/* landscape.css */

#landscape{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your render function is `private`, in that it's only accessible from inside your `sky()` function.

In order for it to work, you need to provide external accessibility (by adding a property to `this`)

Try

```
this.render = function(thecontext) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'm curious as to whether I'm misunderstanding the tutorial over at w3schools (yes, I know, w3fools and all that) or whether they're doing something wrong: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_create_object3 Any insight?

Comment: From the example you've linked: You're missing this line: `this.changeName=changeName;` Which assigns the "private" function changeName, to a publically accessible property.